# How to plot a graph of 3 lines, where one vector holds the y axis and a 3 by X matrix holds the values of the 3 lines?

Tags: matlab, plot

Sorry for the simplicity of the question.  New to Matlab and despite its thorough documentation, can't find this.

I have a vector `y_axis` that has all of the sequential values for my y-axis. It is 400x1.  I also have a matrix `data` where each column holds the corresponding x-axis values.  It is 400x3.

I want to plot a line graph based on this data, but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that your data looks like:

y = [ 2;3;4]
x = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]

You could plot this by:

> > plot(y,x(:,1))
> >
> > hold on
> >
> > plot(y,x(:,2))
> >
> > plot(y,x(:,3))

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks!  Is there any way to distinguish between them once they're plotted?  Like changing a curve's colour?

Comment: plot(y,x(:,1),'LineWidth',2,'Color',[.6 0 0]); hold on; plot(y,x(:,2),'LineWidth',3,'Color',[0 .6 0]); plot(y,x(:,3),'LineWidth',1,'Color',[0 0 .6]);

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply to use the function [PLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) like so:

```
plot(y_axis, data);
```

It will even color each line differently for you.